# Function For Detecting JSON Properties In Non Existing Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

Is there a way to check whether or not a property exists in JSON without providing a specific object?

For example,

```
data.programs.text.background
```

`background` is the property of `text`. But what if a `text` object does not exist in the current object?

JSON:

```
{
    "programs": [
        {
            "width": 500,
            "height": 600,
            "text": {
                "foreground": "black",
                "background": "white"
            }
        },
        {
            "width": 100,
            "height": 200
        },
        {
            "width": 800,
            "height": 300,
            "text": {
                "foreground": "yellow",
                "background": "red"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The console would give an error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'background' of undefined`

Testing for `data.programs.text.background == undefined` does not work.

Can a function be written that detects whether not the object exists and whether or not the property exists by simply providing reference to an object property such as `data.programs.text.background`?

Comment: you might need to traverse to the end of chain and keep on comparing the  nested property one by one

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to determine if an object has the property on the object.

Comment: Not sure if this answers  the question because the OP said "without providing a specific object?"

Answer (score 2):

Traverse the path and use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`

```
function exists(object, path) {
    if (path.length === 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, path[0])
        && exists(object[path[0]], path.slice(1));
}

console.log(exists({}, [ "foo", "bar" ])); // false
console.log(exists({ "foo": { "bar": {} } }, [ "foo", "bar" ])); // true
console.log(exists({ "hasOwnProperty": { "bar": {} } }, [ "hasOwnProperty", "bar" ])); // true

// usage:

exists(data, [ "programs", "text", "background" ]);
```

---

I had another idea.

You could do:

```
function exists(string, context) {
    var parts = string.split("."), part;
    context = context || window;
    while (parts.length > 0) {
        part = parts.shift();
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(context, part) === false) {
            return false;
        }
        context = context[part];
    }
    return true;
}

exists("data.programs.text.background");
```

Comment: Any way to pass the argument in the function in this format? `exists(data.programs.methods)`

Comment: You can't pas it like that because it will be evaluated before it gets passed.  You either pass a value, undefined or you get an Error. You can however pass it as a string: `exists("data.programs.methods")` see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to find is the property present.

```js
var data = {
    "programs": [
        {
            "width": 500,
            "height": 600,
            "text": {
                "foreground": "black",
                "background": "white"
            }
        },
        {
            "width": 100,
            "height": 200
        },
        {
            "width": 800,
            "height": 300,
            "text": {
                "foreground": "yellow",
                "background": "red"
            }
        }
    ]
}

function isPropThere(root, prop){
   var keys = prop.split(/[.,\[\]]+/);
   for(var i=1; i< keys.length; i++){

         root = root[keys[i]]
         console.dir(root)
         if(Array.isArray(root)){
          root = root[keys[++i]];
          continue;
         }
         if(!root){
                return alert('property not present');
         }
   }
 return alert('property present '+root);
}

isPropThere(data, 'data.programs[0].text.background'); // present - white
isPropThere(data, 'data.programs[1].text.background'); // not present
isPropThere(data, 'data.programs[2].text.background'); // present - red
```

Comment: This looks good. Anyway to make the function take only one argument preferably without a string such as `isPropThere(data.programs.methods)` ?

Comment: you can, by using `root = eval(keys[0])` but use of `eval` is not recommended.

Comment: Can you please provide the example? Making root = eval(keys[0]) does not work.

Comment: `function isPropThere(prop){`
   `var keys = prop.split('.');
var root = eval(keys[0]);` & other code remains same & call with `isPropThere(data.programs.methods)`. but remember as I said its not recommended to use `eval` function.

Comment: well obviously.. for `isPropThere(data.programs.methods);` you need to pass argument as string `"data.programs.methods"` as the object doesnt exist itself and for isPropThere('data.programs.width'); is not present is correct outcome because width is not present on programs but in list of it.

Comment: @MCSharp answered your question with latest code.. do check out